# Make the button disappear when the menu is open

Tags: css, wordpress

This is the website I'm working on http://www.jokerleb.com/ and I'm using this https://responsive.menu, the free version. it will appear on devices 400px and smaller.

[image]

I want the button and the word "categories" to disappear when the menu is open. And I want to place the x on the top right.

I tried

```
.responsive-menu-accessible is-active{
  background-color: transparent!important;
}

.responsive-menu-accessible is-active text{
   background-color:transparent!important;
}
```

It doesn't work, how to do it? I can do it from inspect element with some success but I think I'm working with wrong classes.

Comment: Is your is-active and text also a class if it is use .is-active .text? Also better to use display: none if you want to hide something.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the menu in question, but it sounds like `is-active` should actually be `.is-active`. `text` should **possibly** also be `.text`, but I'm not sure if this is referencing a class or the actual text field.

Comment: don't forget the semi-colon at the end of !important - you omitted it, i only noticed it when i was tidying your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px)
(index):172
.responsive-menu-open button#responsive-menu-button .responsive-menu-box {
    color: #fdc300;
    float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px)
(index):172
.responsive-menu-open button#responsive-menu-button:hover, .responsive-menu-open button#responsive-menu-button:focus, button#responsive-menu-button:hover, button#responsive-menu-button:focus {
    background: transparent;
    top: 0!important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px)
(index):172
.responsive-menu-open #responsive-menu-container.push-top, .responsive-menu-open #responsive-menu-container.slide-top {
    transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Change the css to code above and remove the text from responsive-menu-label class.[image: Result]